# Why does Android Studio ask "Remove files from Mercurial" after opening my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, mercurial

From time to time (since yesterday every time) Android Studio askes if it should remove files from Mercurial immediately after opening a project. These files don't exist. There is no "libraries" in ".idea" and even if it was - ".idea" is in hgignore.
Another developer told me that I must close the window by the cross and must not use "ok" or "cancel".
What does Android Studio want from me? How can I get rid of this annoying dialog forever without destroying the project?

[image: remove non-existing files?!]

Answer (score 0):

could be more helpful if you display the `.hgignore` you're using, because in can be glob or not

but if I have to guess, I would say you have `.idea` directory excluded in `.hgignore` but perhaps not its subdirectories

you can try with this `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: glob
.idea/**
```

Comment: You guess right. I'll try it. If the problem doesn't show anymore this week I think it is the solution (but I don't really understand why AS adds temporary files to mercurial).

Comment: Did not work.
`.hgignore`:

    syntax: glob
.gradle
.DS_Store
local.properties
.idea/**
build
*.iml
gradlew
gradlew.bat

*.orig
syntax: regexp
^local\.properties/
^\.idea/
\.iml$
^app/build/
^build/
^captures/

Comment: If you can try (better on a copy) accept the message after having the `.hgignore` like this. Then reopen and see if it is no longer there. I'm thinking perhaps those are already committed and need to be forgotten.

Answer (score -1):

First, use `hg grep` to find the deleted file you wish to recover. The output of this command will show you the last revision for which the file was present, and the path to the deleted file. Second, run `hg revert -r <revision number> <path to deleted file>` The deleted file will now be in your working copy, ready to be committed back into head.

Comment: I don't want to recover any file. The files from the screenshot seem to be made by AS itself (if they ever really existed). The names look like meta data of libraries we use in the project. I just never want to see this dialog again and I don't want to destroy the project. :)